WSL/Ubuntu blocked from DNS when on VPN, not able to ping anything
In WSL/Ubuntu, I updated /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to use 8.8.8.8 as a DNS server (Google's DNS server) and then rebooted. Once back up, before connecting to Trident VPN, I was able to ping google.com, github.com, etc from WSL/Ubuntu without issue. However, once connecting to the Trident VPN, I'm not able to ping anything from WSL/Ubuntu (have explored a number of ideas with no success). Meanwhile, from Windows PowerShell, I've been able to ping pretty much anything whether on or off the VPN. Ultimately, I need to be able to access github.com a

Have you tried adding the default route for WSL to your VPN ? On Windows route add destination_network MASK subnet_mask gateway_ip with -p to make it persistent. This is more a question for Windows though

What's the output of ip a on WSL ? Do you see your VPN ?
